# Android: How to get contents of sms sending from native app before auctually it is sent from the device?

Tags: android, sms

I wanted my app to check for the message contents like originating address(Phone Number) and contents of text before auctually sending it from native sms app. So if you type something in someones thread in native sms app and press send, my app should detect he messasge before it is auctually send and analyze the information and maybe change some info and then send it. Is there any method to do that? Something to stop the other messages to be sent and then analize it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is allowed to perform such interceptions, unless you are running a custom ROM which is modified to suit your needs.

*Reason*: It is a security breach for framework by allowing interference in the processing of other applications.